# With all of love

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, astronauts

I'm looking for a short story I read 20 years ago about a lone astronaut traveling to the edge of our solar system and back.

At the edge of the system he felt waves of love and telepathically understood the race or presence to be saying

> "with all of love".

Comment: See also: [short story about a man who wakes to find that time is running very slowly, but then time speeds up](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40729/short-story-about-a-man-who-wakes-to-find-that-time-is-running-very-slowly-but)

Answer (score 18):

This is "[Common time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Time)" by James Blish. An astronaut travels out of the solar system and encounters an alien intelligence. Although their communication is stilted, their intention is very clearly non-hostile:

> We-they are the clinesterton beademung, with all of love." "With all
>   of love," Garrard echoed.

Comment: Spooky. I just read this yesterday.