# Short story about a man travelling faster than light and time moves very slowly for him

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read a short story about 45 years ago so I think it must have been published in the 70s I can't remember the name or author. The story was in a book of short stories possibility 50 or so.

It’s a short story about a guy travelling faster than light, his first words are "don’t move". He soon figures out time for him is moving very slowly, he watches his mission clock move very slowly. He goes through several emotional states figuring things out, time eventually speeds up again and he reaches his destination.

His is the third mission I think the other 2 disappeared. At his destination he meets with some alien's and they talk in a weird form of English.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [short story about a man who wakes to find that time is running very slowly, but then time speeds up](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40729/short-story-about-a-man-who-wakes-to-find-that-time-is-running-very-slowly-but)

Comment: @Mithoron There's no accepted answer on that question.

Comment: Also unaccepted but correct AFAIK here https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/102159/28516

Comment: @Mithoron - We don't mark [tag:Story-ID] questions as duplicates unless both have an identical accepted answer.

Comment: Same theme... this may help you on your quest: https://www.creepypasta.com/if-youre-armed-and-at-the-glenmont-metro-please-shoot-me/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

“[Common Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Time)” by James Blish, almost certainly.

Here’s how it opens.

> Don’t move.
>
> It was the first thought that came into Garrard’s mind when he awoke,
> and perhaps it saved his life. He lay where he was, strapped against
> the padding, listening to the round hum of the engines. That in itself
> was wrong; he should be unable to hear the overdrive at all.

The aliens are called the clinesterton beademung, which may ring a bell.

If this is the correct answer, the question is a [duplicate](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40729/short-story-about-a-man-who-wakes-to-find-that-time-is-running-very-slowly-but).

Comment: Thats the one.... thank you